# What will happen to my bagels dough as i have put the bicarb in my dough by mistake

Tags: dough

What will happen to my dough as I've put the bicarb into the mix

Comment: We'll have a better sense if you [edit]  to include the recipe, so we'll know how much bicarb to how much other ingredients.

Answer (score 2):

Your bagel dough has no acid for the bicarbonate to react with, as sodium bicarbonate is a base it will give your dough a bitter, slightly metallic flavor, how strong it will be depends on how much you added.

You could continue and see how you get, however I would suggest you test it to see before you invest your time. I suggest you take a small ball of it and boil it in some water, then taste it. You could try it raw but it may not be representative of the cooked result. If the taste is okay you can keep on making it and you should have an okay result.

If the flavor is off you have 2 choices:

- You can try adding an acid to react with the bicarb, like lemon juice or a powder such as cream of tartar. Cream of tartar will add less flavor, lemon juice will change the flavor of the dough. I don't know how this will impact the texture, if you don't mind experimenting this could yield an interesting result
- Discard and start over. I'm all to avoid waste but there are times it's better to accept the loss

Answer (score 0):

They may taste a bit different, depending how much you put in.

Bagels are pretty tolerant. Not likely "ruined."